# SQL Using Where on Isnull column

Tags: sql

I have

```
Select
isnull(s1.column, s.column) Supplier
from table
where
```

I am not sure what to put in the where to filter by supplier name when using the isnull.

Comment: What you want to fetch?

Comment: always specify tag for database engine and version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no actual `Supplier` column, put your filtering condition on the `isnull(s1.column, s.column)` expression:

```
SELECT
ISNULL(s1.column, s.column) Supplier
FROM MyTable
WHERE ISNULL(s1.column, s.column) = 'DesiredValue'
```